# Wifi is working, but can't connect to the Internet

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, tomato

I have a Linksys E1200 v2. I just flashed it with DD-WRT. Wifi is working properly and the signal is pretty strong. However, it won't connect to the Internet so it must be misconfigured. Is there an obvious culprit? Here is a screenshot of the DD-WRT control panel:

[image]

It seems the WAN has no IPv4 address configured, but I am not sure what to do. DHCP should already be enabled as far as I can tell. Thanks.

Note: the router is plugged into my ISP's modem/router, though that has not been an issue with my current/previous routers.

[edit1]

Here are some basic WAN and IP settings.

[image]

[edit2]

Same issue after switching to FreshTomato.

[image]

[edit3]

I forgot to mention that I have three other wifi routers that all work properly in the same context.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the WAN settings? Sometimes what happens is if your ISP-provided device has a built-in router (most new ones do), they assign an IP address, for example, in the `192.168.1.x` range. If your router does it in the same range, you need to change the 3rd number to anything else (0 or 2 are common, but you're not limited by those).

Comment: I added some basic info. Can add more.

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: It either times out, or says the destination is unreachable.

Comment: Is the ISP device in bridged mode?

Comment: The ISP router should be in bridged mode, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a different router already plugged into the ISP device. Since the ISP device was in bridged mode, only one of the two routers was connecting to the Internet. What I ended up doing was daisy chain the routers such that device A was plugged into device B which was plugged into device C. Now the Internet works properly on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: the router is plugged into my ISP's modem/router, though that has not been an issue with my current/previous routers.

This does not mean that it is not a problem now. My internet access got blocked once because my router has made some improper request during setup.
Try and plug the cable in a computer and see whether there is still internet on the cable that goes into your router.

Comment: I have a second wifi router plugged into the ISP device, and Internet is working properly for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced that DHCP is the correct way to connect to your ISP modem/router.

Most of my routers have been configured with a username and password to authenticate. My ISPs have always used PPPoE for this.
For this to work the modem/router of the ISP would be set to "bridge mode" (i.e. the modem would pass everything from your DD-WRT router to the ISP directly. It would not have a DHCP server to give out IP addresses/configuration).

In both of your screenshots I can see that your ISP's modem/router is not giving out an IP address via DHCP (the DNS servers in FreshTomato are OpenDNS servers). As @Harm Campmans said above, some ISPs could block any new equipment connected to a modem. 
EDIT:
I cannot see any problems with your configuration  if DHCP is the right option. You could try the MAC address cloning option and use the same MAC address your functioning router has on its WAN interface. AFAIK To receive an IP address via DHCP your modem would forward your router's MAC address to your ISP's DHCP server.  While I assume that they do not filter access via MAC addresses, as we do not know which ISP you are using the requirements are speculation.

Do you remember needing a username/password before when you used your other working routers?

Comment: No, a username/password has never been needed. I have three other properly working wifi routers. It's just this one that is giving me trouble. Thanks.

Comment: Also, no doubt the ISP device is in bridged mode. But how does that affect this device's configuration?

Comment: I couldn't see your comment regarding the bridged mode on my other browser before posting. If the ISP router was not bridged there would have been a second DHCP server. While it should not interfere as the WAN side is separated from the LAN side, 2 DHCP servers can cause strange behaviour.

Comment: On a hunch, instead of plugging the router into the ISP device, I plugged it into a third router instead. Now it is working! Unlike the ISP device, the third router is not in bridged mode. So this is probably the source of the problem. I am not sure what changes to make in FreshTomato however. Right now it is set to "Access Point". Not sure what to select instead. The options are, "Access Point", "Access Point + WDS", "Wireless Client", "Wireless Ethernet Bridge", and "WDS". And I don't know if there are additional changes to be made.

Comment: Right now I think your setup is: ISP modem (bridged) -> WAN (DHCP - public IP address) Router LAN (192.168.x.x private DHCP) -> WAN (DHCP) tomato router.......... The rest of the configuration depends on what you want to achieve. Access Point would be the normal setup to give Internet access via WiFi. Your tomato router should run on a different subnet as mentioned in nurchi's comment. It would NAT twice, which is not ideal. I am gone for the weekend. Maybe you can create a new question once you know what you want to have as the outcome